# Does anyone use a CLOUD Message queue service?

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, soa

I am looking for a case study of companies that use Cloud message queueing.
What are the benefits of such a service over rabbitmq (if any)
I know there are several mature services like SQS of amazon, OnlineMQ and Linxter.

Answer (score 2):

The advantage of Cloud Messaging service is the managing the MQ systems is not your head-ache. It is being pushed to the cloud service provider. Amazon SQS integrated very well with other Amazon AWS products like EC2,S3 so it is the choice if you are already on Amazon AWS infrastructure. But SQS performance way is low compared to RabbitMQ in terms of latency.

So if you want a Message Queue service which has customized needs, RabbitMQ (or any other MQ system) can be what you are looking for.

Comment: We built IronMQ by Iron.io. Another option. More flexible than SQS, you can use our managed cloud service or download it and run it on your own, etc.